# Dreamweaver wildcard find and replace assistance

Tags: replace, dreamweaver, wildcard

I was following [this article](http://vinces.net/2011/04/dreamweaver-wildcard/) about find and replace but have not been able to get it working for what I need to do...

What I need to find and replace it all links that contain `../external.html?link=something.html` and replace them with #

This is what I tried to do in dreamweaver search
*FIND:*

```
<a href="../external.html?link=[^<]*"
```

*REPLACE WITH*

```
<a href="#"
```

But the problem is using that search does not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out from adobe documentation on the subject: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7c3ea.html#WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7c1fa

The problem was that because the string i was search for had ? in it and the wildcard search is a regular expression. So to fix it I had to put a back slash before the ? character e.g: \? 
This escapes the character and I was able to complete my task.

Hopefuly someone else who gets confused on this subject will find this helpful!